# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-cli

I don't know why I keep getting this error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

my requirements.txt file already had flask for deploying
Below is the requirements.txt file

```
certifi==2022.6.15
click==8.1.3
distlib==0.3.4
filelock==3.7.1
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
importlib-metadata==4.11.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pipenv==2022.6.7
platformdirs==2.5.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.37
virtualenv==20.14.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zipp==3.8.0
```

The error code I'm getting in my log

```
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407164+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-22 01:07:09 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407165+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407166+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407166+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407166+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407167+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407167+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407167+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407168+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407169+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407169+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407169+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407170+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407170+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407172+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407172+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407172+00:00 app[web.1]: from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for,session,flash,g
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407172+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
2022-06-22T01:07:09.407278+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-22 01:07:09 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-06-22T01:07:09.444230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-22 01:07:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-06-22T01:07:09.444278+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-22 01:07:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-06-22T01:07:09.599749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-06-22T01:07:09.919297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-22T01:07:26.962605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=busayojee.herokuapp.com request_id=9e644d91-198f-4bf6-9f05-9210508ebc54 fwd="212.175.35.83" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The first few lines of my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for,session,flash,g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import desc

app = Flask(__name__)
```

And my profile contains

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Please I am new to Heroku and any form of help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: what is the context of the python interpreter that's executing your code? Are you running it in docker? I've had these issues when I forget to activate my venv or actually run the `pip install` line into my venv.

Comment: @Chris yes i have a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock could that be the problem?

Comment: @am_an_attendant_lord No I am not running it in docker, do you mean activate my venv in the heroku interface or just activating it on my local interface because I did the latter

Comment: @AlabiOluwabusayoJoseph, yes, that's the problem. Please see the marked duplicates.

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me. I just deleted them both