# Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError :No module named 'six'

Tags: python, django, heroku, modulenotfounderror

I am deploying a Django app on Heroku. The application runs successfully on my local machine, which uses Python 3.6.3.rc1. But it failed to deploy ([heroku activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRGg5.jpg)).

```
remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Actually, It was always successful to build and deploy before August 17 2022.

```
$ git push heroku master
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in Pipfile.lock
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.7.14
remote: -----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
remote:        Skipping installation, as Pipfile.lock has not changed since last deploy.
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Skipping Django collectstatic since the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is set.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 74.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v492
remote:        https://license-web-test.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
remote:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
remote:     self.check()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
remote:     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
remote:     issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
remote:     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
remote:     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
remote:     return check_resolver(resolver)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
remote:     return check_method()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
remote:     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
remote:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
remote:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
remote:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
remote:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/backend/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:     path('api/', include('backend.api.urls'))
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
remote:     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/backend/api/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:     from . import views
remote:   File "/app/backend/api/views.py", line 28, in <module>
remote:     from googleapiclient import discovery
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:     import six
remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
```

After that day. I don't know why I keep getting this error.
According to
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708725/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-flask-heroku), I tried to use
`pipenv install six`to modify `pipfile` & `pipfile.lock` then push heroku.
It can solve this problem but cause other problem one by one.

I also tried roll back the version which build and deploy successfully(Versions prior to August 17, 2022) by `git reset --hard`but all in vain.

Comment: Is it in your requirements.txt file? If it is try adding it to the top for your file.

Comment: @Reventlow, OP says they have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, so Heroku will use Pipenv instead of pip. A `requirements.txt` file would be completely ignored.

Comment: "I tried to use `pipenv install six`to modify `pipfile` & `pipfile.lock` then push heroku. It can solve this problem but cause other problem one by one." Well, that's the solution. Unless you can remove your dependency on `six`, it must be declared as a dependency. You should be asking about the "other problems" that this causes. (Side note: all file name are case-sensitive on Heroku. `pipfile` is different from `Pipfile`, etc. I think your files are actually named correctly, as you are using the `pipenv` command to modify them.)

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the reply. I will try that. But I would like to know why the deployment failed after August 17, 2022 without any changes in the requirements file. I checked the build log on heroku and found that the setuptools version changed from 60.10.0 to 63.4.3. could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Hukys, it's hard to say without more information. The errors you haven't shared might be helpful. Did you make any non-requirements changes? Are all of your requirements pinned to specific versions? Have you changed your stack? Is your version of Python locked down?